# Concurrency and Race Conditions

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I have an "A" system under a firmware and another "B" system under linux.
How to manage Concurrency and Race Conditions on a **B device** system  between B system  and  A system ?.

Comment: Very carefully. Actually, your question is a bit vague.

Comment: Proper use of locks, memory barriers and shared memory.